# IndexOf function in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string

Given an email address column, I need to find the position of the @ sign for substringing.

What is the `indexof` function, for strings in T-SQL?

Looking for something that returns the position of a substring within a string.

in C#

```cs
var s = "abcde";
s.IndexOf('c'); // yields 2
```

Answer (score 263, accepted):

[CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) is what you are looking for

```
select CHARINDEX('@', 'someone@somewhere.com')
-----------
8

(1 row(s) affected)
```

-or-

```
select CHARINDEX('c', 'abcde')
-----------
3

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 73):

You can use either [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) or [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql) to return the starting position of the specified expression in a character string.

```
CHARINDEX('bar', 'foobar') == 4
PATINDEX('%bar%', 'foobar') == 4
```

Mind that you need to use the wildcards in PATINDEX on either side.

Answer (score 37):

One very small nit to pick:

The RFC for email addresses allows the first part to include an "@" sign if it is quoted. Example:

```
"john@work"@myemployer.com
```

This is quite uncommon, but could happen. Theoretically, you should split on the *last* "@" symbol, not the first:

```
SELECT LEN(EmailField) - CHARINDEX('@', REVERSE(EmailField)) + 1
```

More information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Comment: these are the kinds of things that I'm trying to determine and fix in our database. Mainly people just mis type their domain name. most web redirect back to the real one but the mx records don't forward, and displaying them gets awkward

Comment: There's a special place in heck for people who put @'s in the first part of their email addresses ... like people who put spaces in table/field names ...

Answer (score 11):

I believe you want to use `CHARINDEX`. You can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql).