# How to detect if a period is at the beginning of a string?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this query that pulls email addresses from our DB.  There is a lot of junk data, so I only want to see valid email addresses.  Here is my syntax:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Email
FROM         dbo.Customers
WHERE     (Email IS NOT NULL) 
AND (Email LIKE '%@%') 
AND (RIGHT(Email, 4) IN ('.net', '.com', '.org')) 
AND (Email NOT LIKE '%@UniformCity.com') 
AND (Email NOT LIKE '%@LifeUniform.com') 
AND (RIGHT(RTRIM(Email), 1) <> '.') AND (LEFT(LTRIM(Email), 1) <> '@')  --first character not @
AND (Email not Like '%[`:;_*-,()+%\/=#-]%') order by Email
```

I want to detect periods at the beginning of the email.  Also as a bonus, how can I tell my like statement to look for "[" without screwing it up?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you might want to consider doing the filtering in a .NET user-defined function inside the database rather than a T-SQL expression. You will have access to the full power of the CLR's string and regex classes to help you. Performance should not be affected because with an expression like that you are guaranteed a table scan.

Comment: I've never heard of this before.  How would I set that up?

Comment: Try this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Interesting.  I'll take a look at it.  Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [IndexOf function in t-Sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869465/indexof-function-in-t-sql)

Comment: UDF seems a bit over-kill for this sort of thing, unless it's going to be repeated in several locations, no?  Key thing with databases is keep everything as simple as possible, and don't add complexity until you need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
AND (CHARINDEX('.', Email) <> 1)
```

For the `[]`, you could just change the escape character?

```
AND (Email not Like '%[`:;_*-,^[^]()+%\/=#-]%' ESCAPE '^')
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: "For the [], you could just change the escape character?" -- while that's correct, I think it would be helpful to demonstrate this.

Comment: I provided a link to the relevant documentation.  It's better to read that, with all the implications, than me post a trivial example I made up on the spot with incomplete information that might be misleading.  Especially as that wasn't the question - it was a "oh, and also..." tag-along.

Comment: totally disagree with you.  It's better to show a concise example that illustrates the solution.  In fact, it's **far** better to do so.

Comment: Fine.  Added example to not-the-actual-question for the lazy.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to do this using T-SQL?  If so, what version of SQL Server?  (from your tags I assume SQL Server 2008)

Question for you .. why not run a program against the database to scrub it?  Extract all the e-mails addresses, use a Regular Expression to determine whether or not each one is valid, and flag (or remove) the invalid addresses.

*** UPDATE: I agree with Christian Hayter! ***

Comment: I realize you don't have the rep, but answers should be answers, and this is merely a comment.

Comment: While phrased as a question.... the statement "why not run a program against the database to scrub it?" could be considered an answer because it offers an alternate solution...